# MVC Multiple Areas MVC 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to get MVC Multiple areas working with MVC 3.0 RC

I've downloaded MVC Futures 3 and tried adding the CreateAreaManifest to the csprog file 
But i'm getting the following error:

"The "Microsoft.Web.Mvc.Build.CreateAreaManifest" task could not be loaded from the assembly Microsoft.Web.Mvc.Build, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null. Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Web.Mvc.Build, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that the  declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask."

From everything google tells me. I need to install it into the GAC which I can't do because it's not strongly typed.

So I guess I'm asking for some help getting Multiple Areas working with MVC 3.0 and a link to a demo project would be perfect

Answer (score 2):

Chris,

Are you specifically trying to utilise Areas from separate projects?

If so, see [Stack Overflow: Multiproject Areas in ASP.NET MVC 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3966124/multiproject-areas-in-asp-net-mvc-3).

Alternatively, MVC 3 RC has the ability to create multiple Areas built into it (I'm not sure whether this is also the case for MVC 3 Beta / Preview).

By right clicking on the name of the project, you should see this menu:
[image: Add Area]

Note, I am using Visual Studio 2010 with MVC 3 RC.

Whilst I have not actually utilised these so can not confirm their valid functionality, I find it strange that the option would exist if they did not function...

I hope this helps!

Mark