# Portable Areas Vs Multi project Areas?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvccontrib, asp.net-mvc-areas, portable-areas

Can you please tell me advantages/drawbacks of these two implementations?

My context : We have a large project which includes many differents domains. Each domain will naturally be  an Area. But many differents teams will work on each and we want to separate business rules. What is the best way to manage these ares in a solution ?

I have seen many examples of Areas in separate project or with portable areas.
But i can not take decision.

From my point of view :

Separate Project

- Simple
- Difficult to manage Content (JS, CSS, ...). Does it must be in the main site ?
- Best performances

Portable Areas

- All content, views must be in the same project
- Possible code duplicate between areas
- Contraints : name , embedded ressources, ...
- Part of MVC Contrib : will it me supported longer ?
- Component : ideal for redistribute a feature

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I'm facing the same problem, and have been checking for it.
The following link is something about portable areas. The first answer is given by the lead of MS MVC development team. Although it can not answer the question, wish it can help you a litle.

[Multiproject areas in ASP.Net MVC 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3966124/multiproject-areas-in-asp-net-mvc-3)